# KeyError: [columns] not in index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
cols = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4']
df = df[cols]
```

And I'm getting the following error to the last line:

> KeyError: "['Column1' 'Column2' 'Column3'\n 'Column4'] not in index

I don't know why it's adding that newline after Column3 or if that is even the issue. Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's not my script, but I believe this section is attempting to create a DataFrame of those columns that will then be populated with a subsequent for loop.

Answer (score 2):

In order to initialize an empty data frame with named columns, you pass the columns as an argument:

```py
cols = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
```

Comment: That does indeed create df. But I run into another error later. It may be a Pandas version issue. I'm on 0.23.4. Can that explain why my sample code returns that error?

Comment: Your sample code is trying to access columns that don't exist. You created an empty data frame with no columns (```df = pd.DataFrame()```), then try to access named columns (```df = df[cols]```). It's not a version issue.